# Is there any trick that allows to use Management Studio's (ver. 2008) IntelliSense feature with earlier versions of SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, intellisense

New version of Management Studio (i.e. the one that ships with SQL Server 2008) finally has a Transact-SQL IntelliSense feature. However, out-of-the-box it only works with SQL Server 2008 instances.

Is there some workaround for this?

Comment: Red Gate Sql Prompt at <http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm> provides intellisense and more for MS SQL

Comment: Agreed. My team and I use SQL Prompt and it's a valuable tool. Download a trial and try it for yourself.

Answer (score 8):

There's no known trick 'in the wild' for getting around this, other than using CTP-6 of SQL Server 2008 (in favour of the RTM).

the reasons for removing backward compatability (and a lot more discussion besides) are provided at the [relevant feedback in microsoft connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=341872).

edit: sorry i don't know where this ctp is available, if at all

Comment: Why the emphasis on 'in the wild'. Is there some top secret way to enable it?

Answer (score 1):

Has anyone tried either patching SSMS not to check the version (perhaps try looking at the binary differences between CTP 6 and RTM?), or patching SS 2005 to pretend to be 2008?

Unclean, I know, but I don't see any other way.